# error: GenerateFeatureFileCodeBehindTask task could not be loaded from the assembly

Tags: .net-core, specflow, build-error

We have ported our project from .NET to .NET Core in order to use an AWS pipeline with Docker containers which requires Linux.

The application builds successfully on our local computers (which run Windows) but in the AWS pipeline the build steps shows this error - `GenerateFeatureFileCodeBehindTask ... task could not be loaded from the assembly ... SpecFlow.Tools.MsBuild.Generation.dll`:

Full error:

```
/root/.nuget/packages/specflow.tools.msbuild.generation/3.0.225/build/SpecFlow.Tools.MsBuild.Generation.targets(78,5): error MSB4062: The "SpecFlow.Tools.MsBuild.Generation.GenerateFeatureFileCodeBehindTask" task could not be loaded from the assembly /root/.nuget/packages/specflow.tools.msbuild.generation/3.0.225/build/../tasks/netcoreapp2.0/SpecFlow.Tools.MsBuild.Generation.dll. Assembly with same name is already loaded Confirm that the <UsingTask> declaration is correct, that the assembly and all its dependencies are available, and that the task contains a public class that implements
     Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask. [/codebuild/output/src814/src/s3/00/ProjectFoo/ProjectFoo.csproj]
```

I have found 2 links mentioning this error but no solution - https://ci.appveyor.com/project/SpecFlow/specflow-kx1o3/build/build1119 and https://www.gitmemory.com/issue/techtalk/SpecFlow/1699/520196304.

I have checked and I have no `<UsingTask>` in my csproj files. Any idea what this SpecFlow task is, and why it is throwing this error?

Answer (score 1):

The `GenerateFeatureFileCodeBehindTask` is contained in the `SpecFlow.Tools.MSBuild.Generation` package. It is used to generate the code-behind files of your feature files.

You don't find a `<UsingTask>` because it is done in the NuGet package.

The GitHub issue for this is: https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/issues/1699/
Currently I have no idea why this error is thrown. But we are currently fixing our build/tests for Linux.

Comment: I fixed the error by a certain stub project from the solution. This project was unnecessary and had been auto-generated. It's presence in the solution  caused the error in the other projects. But I didn't have time to investigate what exactly is causing the error. Probably it has a version conflict for nuget packages or something like that.

Comment: I have fixed the error by uninstalling the package SpecFlow.Tools.MSBuild.Generation from Visual Studio. Let me know if anyone able to fix this issue?

Comment: @JanardhanReddy You need this package to use SpecFlow. If you have problems with it, please open an issue on GitHub.